# iCloud sign into new device triggers notification or email?

Tags: icloud

If I sign into someone else's icloud from a device that they have never signed into it from,  will they get a notification or a email?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

They will get an email with the details which Device is used to login with their iCloud account.

If that iCloud account uses Two Factor Authentication they also get a notification including the location where the request is made.